# How to conceptualize Django's ForeignKey?

Tags: django, foreign-key-relationship

I read the docs for ForeignKey and it says that Foreign Key gives a Many-To-One relationship.

I made this example to say that each ChatRoom can have multiple messages:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    message=models.CharField(max_length=30)

class ChatRoom(models.Model):
    message=models.ForeignKey(Message)
```

Does this code achieve that? If not, I guess the right answer should be this

```
class ChatRoom(models.Model):
    room_name=models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Message(models.Model):
    message=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    room=models.ForeignKey(ChatRoom)
```

In any case, how would I go about displaying all the messages in the ChatRoom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the right models declaration for your purposes (the second one):

```
class ChatRoom(models.Model):
    room_name=models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Message(models.Model):
    message=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    room=models.ForeignKey(ChatRoom)
```

It means that there are more messages (many) related to a single chat room(one).

To display all the messages, you do:

```
messages = chat_room.message_set.values('message')
```

where chat_room is an instance of `ChatRoom` model

Or, you can make a related name:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    message=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    room=models.ForeignKey(ChatRoom, related_name='messages')
```

and then, do

```
messages = chat_room.messages.values('message')
```

to actually take all the messages, or

`messages = chat_room.messages.all()`

to take all the objects (not just the message)

Answer (score 1):

```
class ChatRoom(models.Model):
    room_name=models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Message(models.Model):
    message=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    room=models.ForeignKey(ChatRoom)
```

For displaying all the messages of a chatroom use:

```
chatroomobject.message_set.all() in backend views/scripts
chatroomobject.message_set.all in templates
```

here:

```
chatroomobject is the instance object of the ChatRoom Model
```